# Do uniaxial lossy media rotate the polarization of the extraordinary wave?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, polarization

I am having problems determining the direction of polarization (of the electric field) of the extraordinary wave in a uniaxial crystal when the media is lossy. I am especially interested in the propagation of a transmitted wave. In the absence of free charges:

\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
\nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{D} = 0.
\end{equation}

For plane-wave solution ($\boldsymbol{D}=\boldsymbol{D}_{\boldsymbol{k}}e^{\boldsymbol{k} \cdot \boldsymbol{r}- \omega t}$) Eq. (1) becomes:

\begin{equation}
\tag{2}
\boldsymbol{k} \cdot \boldsymbol{D}_\boldsymbol{k} = 0.
\end{equation}

If we assume the anisotropy is of the following form:
\begin{equation}
\tag{3}
\varepsilon = \begin{pmatrix}
\varepsilon_x & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \varepsilon_x & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \varepsilon_z
\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
where $\varepsilon_x$ and $\varepsilon_z$ are complex numbers (lossy media). And, for simplicity, we restrict the propagation to the xz-plane (plane of incidence), we obtain:
\begin{equation}
\tag{4}
k_x \varepsilon_x (\boldsymbol{E}_\boldsymbol{k})_x + k_z \varepsilon_z (\boldsymbol{E}_\boldsymbol{k})_z = 0,
\end{equation}
here $(\boldsymbol{E}_\boldsymbol{k})_a$ is the $a$ component of the electric field.

Eq. (4) has two solutions:
\begin{equation}
\tag{5}
\text{ordinary}: \boldsymbol{k}=\boldsymbol{q}=(q_x,0,q_z) \qquad \boldsymbol{E}_\boldsymbol{q}=(0,A,0)\\
\text{extraordinary}: \boldsymbol{k}=\boldsymbol{p}=(p_x,0,p_z) \qquad \boldsymbol{E}_\boldsymbol{p}=(-p_z \varepsilon_z B,0,p_x \varepsilon_x B)
\end{equation}
where, in general, $A$ and $B$ are complex numbers. Note that: $\boldsymbol{q}\neq \boldsymbol{p}$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birefringence).

The polarization of the ordinary wave is easy to determine (perpendicular to the plane of incidence [y-axis]), even for lossy media! However, the extraordinary wave is not so easy to interpret. When the media is lossless, the angle ($\theta$) between the direction of propagation $(p_x,0,p_z)$ and the direction of polarization of the field ($\boldsymbol{E}_\boldsymbol{p}$) satisfies:
\begin{equation}
\tag{6}
\boldsymbol{p}\cdot\boldsymbol{E}_\boldsymbol{p} = |\boldsymbol{p}||\boldsymbol{E}_\boldsymbol{p}|\cos(\theta)\\
\cos(\theta) = \frac{p_x p_z (-\varepsilon_z+\varepsilon_x)}{\sqrt{p_x^2+p_x^2}\sqrt{\varepsilon_z^2p_z^2+\varepsilon_x^2p_x^2}}
\end{equation}
which reduces to the well-known fact that $\boldsymbol{p}$ and $\boldsymbol{E}_\boldsymbol{p}$ are perpendicular for isotropic media. Eq. (6) is well-defined because for lossless media all the numbers are real.

For lossy media, $\varepsilon_x$ and $\varepsilon_z$ have an imaginary part, and so do $p_x$ and $p_z$. This implies that $\boldsymbol{E}_\boldsymbol{p}$ is a vector of complex entries, correct? Does the relative phase difference and magnitude between $(-p_z \varepsilon_z)$ and $(p_x \varepsilon_x)$ imply that the direction of polarization of the extraordinary wave follows an ellipse in the xz-plane? Once you introduce the time dependence, I imagine that the polarization will follow something like a cycloid (but with an ellipse). Is my intuition correct?

I add an image for clarity
[image: The direction of polarization of the extraordinary ray for a lossy uniaxial media follows and ellipse? The image shows a cut in the xz-plane]